# Reference route with parameter - Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I have a route that I declare like so;

```
Route::get('invite/{code}', ['middleware' => ['qwickLoggedIn'], 'uses' =>'WebController@signup_invite'])->name('signup_invite');
```

As you can see the route has a parameter `{code}`
How can I reference the route using `route` or `url`?

Like in the code below?

```
public function account_verification () {

    $referer = Request::header('referer');

    if ($referer != url('login') && $referer != url('signup') && $referer != url('invite/{code}') && $referer != url('account-verification-code')) {
        return redirect()->route('/');
    }

    $year = $this->copyright_info('2015');
    return view('pages.account-verification', ['year' => $year]);
}
```

I put is as `$referer != url('invite/{code}')` but this doesn't work. also `$referer != url('invite')` doesn't work as well... Also using `route('signup_invite');`

I get the error `UrlGenerationException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: signup_invite] [URI: invite/{code}].`

Any help appreciated

Comment: You mean `$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);`

Comment: @JilsonThomas the code above is in my `controller` I use the if statement to ensure that the page is only accessed via certain pages. So I'm checking the `referrer` the only issue here is that how do I reference a `url` with a parameter... Also the parameter can be anything

Comment: You can use the `route('routeName')` and `route('routeName', ['code' => 123]);` for this.

Comment: I tried the first option and I get the error stated above. As for the second option the parameter will not be `123` and is dynamic... will it still work if I put a dummy parameter?

Comment: yes, just use some dummy parameter

Comment: The easiest way that I can think of to match a url pattern with dynamic parameters as in your case would to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

It looks messy, but you can parse `$referrer` using `parse_url` function & then put conditions for the components:

```
$referer = Request::header('referer');

$path = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_PATH);
$path = explode( '/', $path );

if ($referer != url('login') && $referer != url('signup') && ( parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_HOST) == parse_url( url('/'), PHP_URL_HOST ) && $path[1] == 'invite' && !empty($path[2]) ) && $referer != url('account-verification-code')) {
    return redirect()->route('/');
}
```